# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. & finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: flutter, gradle

I tried to run my app, but I encountered this error

[image]

Comment: Have you clear build?

Comment: Yes, I have , but it doesn't work.

Comment: It may be some other issue, need to check!

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this ndk apiFilters thing into app level build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
    }
}
```

Comment: This part was set, but it did not work.